# How to Remove caavg_private Properly on AIX?

Tags: aix, cluster

I am trying to cleanup a server which had a PowerHA configuration. I have stopped cluster (`smitty clstop`) and removed resource groups. How do I remove the caavg_private properly?

```
hdisk5 00cc90476e2a44dd caavg_private active

# lsvg -l caavg_private
caavg_private:
LV NAME TYPE LPs PPs PVs LV STATE MOUNT POINT
caalv_private1 boot 1 1 1 closed/syncd N/A
caalv_private2 boot 1 1 1 closed/syncd N/A
caalv_private3 boot 4 4 1 open/syncd N/A
powerha_crlv boot 1 1 1 closed/syncd N/A

# clstat -o
clstat - HACMP Cluster Status Monitor
-------------------------------------
Cluster: <ClName> (1591186363)
Wed Apr 1 03:57:10 2020
State: UP Nodes: 2
SubState: STABLE
Node: Node01 State: UP
Interface: Node01 (0) Address: 10.x.x.x
State: UP
Node: Node02 State: UP
Interface: Node02 (0) Address: 10.x.x.x
State: UP
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a volume group from an AIX system, simply export it. One of the logical volumes (caalv_private3) is still "open", though, so you'll first need to close it and vary off the VG. You've shown that caalv_private3 has a LV Type of "boot", which means it probably is not mounted, and should close on its own with the VG going offline.

1. `varyoffvg caavg_private`
2. `exportvg caavg_private`

Further reading:

- [AIX 7.2 - Device management - Logical volume storage - Logical volume storage concepts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/devicemanagement/volgroups.html)
- [AIX 7.2 - Device management - Logical volume storage - Configuring Logical Volume Storage - Removing a disk while the system remains available](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/devicemanagement/removediskdata.html)

Answer (score 0):

Caavg_private is part of Cluster Aware AIX used by PowerHA. You need to completely remove PowerHA cluster configuration not only resource group. 
run:

```
#clmgr delete cluster NODES=ALL
```

it will remove powerha cluster with caa

if somehow caavg_private stays (check if CAA cluster is running with lscluster) 
and remove it with:

```
#CAA_FORCE_ENABLED=1 rmcluster –fr <caa_vg_private_hdisk>
```